# Spring mongo repository: find top n items

Tags: spring, mongodb, repository

I have a spring backend with mongodb. I want to query the db to get 'n' POIs (points of interest) within a box. This query works fine

`poisRepository.findTop10ByLocationWithin(box);`

but I would like to extend it to something like this:

`poisRepository.findTopXByLocationWithin(10, box);`

I can't find how to do that in the documentation. Is there another way to do this, except getting all results and filtering them through code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to this using [@Query](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query) from spring and [$box mongo query](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/box/#op._S_box)

In my implementation I finally used the following approach, with paging

```
Pageable pageRequest = new PageRequest(page, pageSize);
Page<Poi> poisPage = poisRepository.findByLocationWithin(box, pageRequest);
List<Poi> pois = poisPage.getContent();
```

So if I need the top 20 pois, I pass 20 as the pageSize and so on. Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Hello @Marco, I added the snippet from the code I wrote, check it out